# How did Krishna justify war?

Tags: mahabharata, gita

So in the Geeta in the Mahabharata, there's a moment where Krishna is asked by Arjun to paraphrase: "if I withhold my vengeance so many lives will be saved. For what then should I proceed?" He asks god Krishna.

What philosophical moves does the god make to justify the coming war?

Comment: Kr̥ṣṇa didn't justify war, he justified duty and responsibility primarily in the first case (as in the case of Arjuna's intent of deserting). Kr̥ṣṇa didn't even want a war to happen in the first place, he was of the ones who knew the wrongs of both the Pāṇḍavas and Kauravas and despite his best efforts, he couldn't stop it, because both parties wanted it. But when the war already had begun, running away from it was no solution. Some may say, that Kr̥ṣṇa is God so why can't he stop the war?

Comment: Well, the divine as in Kr̥ṣṇa won't intrude with free will and karma of humans, and also he is not omnipotent in his human form, being an Īśvara, he is subject to karma as well in his mortal life.

Comment: @Bingming , In my understanding,Avataaraas(AV) shareer is aprakrutha , as  isnt born out of Karma . Also, any AVs act is considered Lila ,(undriven by any natural impulses). AV can subdue Maya,(Lord Krishna advanced Sunset etc.) , hence has the power to change the law of nature.When it is true that a yogi can attain omniscience and omnipotence (according to Rishi Patanjali), how come  an Avatara of Ishwara is incapable of it.  Foll. ans.( uttanka episode) stands as an evidence .

Comment: @Athrey Well, I also was referring to Utaṅka's episode as well. The only difference is that our interpretations are different. If you are interesting in exploring more of what I said and the reasons of why I declare Kr̥ṣṇa to be not omnipotent. I would recommend you to check the essay, 'Kr̥ṣṇa: In Defence of Devious Divinity'  by B.K. Matilal. He didn't change the laws of nature in the battle, he just took advantage of a natural eclipse. Of course Kr̥ṣṇa devotees, may perceive things differently. According to me, Kr̥ṣṇa was knowledgeable enough to know that a solar eclipse was going to occur.

Comment: Omnipotence is actually not a feature of Hindu gods to be honest, although some fanatical devotees may say so. It's more of Judeo-Christian aspect. And that's the reason why there is no place for the 'Problem of Evil' actually in Hindu framework. The notions of God in Hindu nowadays are quite often wrongly interpreted in Abrahamic sense or western way by many contemporary devotees.

Comment: It is significant to know that after Duryodhana's fall, Kr̥ṣṇa greeted King Yudhiṣṭhira with a long speech, which was interspersed with the expression *diṣṭyā-vardhase* (you have achieved the victory luckily). It was a plain admission that the Pāṇḍavas won against all odds because of luck, not through the omnipotence of Kr̥ṣṇa.
Note that when I mentioned Hindu gods, I was referring to gods like Kr̥ṣṇa in Mahābhārata (excluding Bhagavad Gītā) and Rāma in Rāmāyaṇa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utanka, an ascetic, asked Sri Krishna why he didn't stop the war. Sri Krishna's answer was that he did his best but failed to change the mind of the Kauravas. He didn't give any philosophical reason.

**Utanka’s curse**

> "Utanka said,--'Since, though able, O Krishna, thou didst not rescue
> those foremost ones of Kuru's race, who were thy relatives and,
> therefore, dear to thee, I shall, without doubt, curse thee. Since
> thou didst not forcibly compel them to forbear, therefore, O slayer of
> Madhu, I shall, filled with wrath, denounce a curse on thee. It seems,
> O Madhava, that though fully able (to save them), thou wert
> indifferent to these foremost of Kurus who, overwhelmed by insincerity
> and hypocrisy have all met with destruction.'
>
> "Vasudeva said, 'O scion
> of Bhrigu's race, listen to what I say in detail. Do thou accept my
> apologies also. O thou of Bhrigu's race, thou art an ascetic. After
> having heard my words relating to the soul, thou mayst then utter thy
> curse. No man is able, by a little ascetic merit, to put me down. O
> foremost of ascetics, I do not wish to see the destruction of all thy
> penances. Thou hast a large measure of blazing penances. Thou hast
> gratified thy preceptors and seniors. 2 O foremost of regenerate ones,
> I know that thou hast observed the rules of Brahmacharyya from the
> days of thy infancy. I do not, therefore, desire the loss or
> diminution of thy penances achieved with so much pain.'"
>
> “Utanka said,
> 'Do thou, O Kesava, tell me that faultless Adhyatma. Having heard thy
> discourse I shall ordain what is for thy good or denounce a curse to
> thee, O Janarddana.'
>
> "Vasudeva said, 'Know that the three qualities of
> Darkness and Passion and Goodness exist, depending on me as their
> refuge. So also, O regenerate one, know that the Rudras and the Vasus
> have sprung from me. In me are all creatures, and in all creatures do
> I exist; know this. Let no doubt arise in thy mind respecting this. So
> also, O regenerate one, know that all the tribes of the Daityas, all
> the Yakshas, Gandharvas, Rakshasas, Nagas. Apsaras, have sprung from
> me. Whatever has been called existent and non-existent, whatever is
> manifest and not-manifest, whatever is destructible and
> indestructible, all have me for their soul. Those fourfold courses of
> duty which, O ascetic, are known to attach to the (four) modes of
> life, and all the Vedic duties, have me for their soul. Whatever is
> non-existent, whatever is existent and non-existent, and whatever
> transcends that which is existent and non-existent,--all these which
> constitute the universe--are from me. There is nothing higher (or
> beyond) me who am the eternal god of gods. 1 O perpetuator of Bhrigu's
> race, know that all the Vedas beginning with (the original syllable)
> Om are identical with me. Know, O son of Bhrigu's race, that I am the
> sacrificial stake; I am the Soma (drunk in sacrifices); I am the Charu
> (cooked in sacrifices for being offered to the deities); I am the Homa
> (that is performed); I am those acts which sacrificers perform for
> gratifying the deities; I am even the pourer of the sacrificial
> libation: and I am the Havi or libation that is poured. I am the
> Adharyu. I am the Kalpaka; and I am the highly sanctified sacrificial
> Havi. It is me whom the Udgatri, in the great sacrifice, hymns by the
> sound of his songs. In all rites of expiation, O Brahmana, the
> utterers of auspicious Mantras and benedictions fraught with peace
> hymn my praises who am the artificer, O foremost of regenerate ones,
> of the universe. Know, O best of regenerate person, that Dharma is my
> eldest-born offspring, sprung from my mind, O learned Brahmana, whose
> essence is compassion for all creatures. Constantly transforming
> myself, I take birth in diverse wombs, O best of men, for upholding
> that son of mine, with the aid of men now existing in or departed from
> the world. Indeed, I do this for protecting Righteousness and for
> establishing it. In those forms that I assume for the purpose, I am
> known, O son of Bhrigu's race, in the three worlds as Vishnu and
> Brahman and Sakra. I am the origin and I am the destruction of all
> things. I am the creator of all existent objects and I am their
> destroyer. Knowing no change myself, I am the destroyer of all those
> creatures that live in sinfulness. In every Yuga I have to repair the
> causeway of Righteousness, entering into diverse kinds of wombs from
> desire of doing good to my creatures. **When, O son of Bhrigu's race, I
> live in the order of the deities, I then verily act in every respect
> as a deity. When I live in the order of the Gandharvas, I then, O son
> of Bhrigu's race, act in every respect as a Gandharva. When I live in
> the order of the Nagas, I then act as a Naga, and when I live in the
> order of Yakshas or that of Rakshasas, I act after the manner of that
> order. Born now in the order of humanity, I must act as a human being.
> I appealed to them (the Kauravas) most piteously. But stupefied as
> they were and deprived of their senses, they refused to accept my
> words. I frightened them, filled with wrath, referring to some great
> fear (as the consequence of their slighting my message). But once more
> I showed themselves my usual (human) form. Possessed as they were of
> unrighteousness, and assailed by the virtue of Time, all of them have
> been righteously slain in battle, and have, without doubt, gone to
> Heaven. The Pandavas also, O best of Brahmanas, have acquired great
> fame. I have thus told thee all that thou hadst asked me.'"**

**Mahabharata, Aswamedha Parva, Section LIII-LIV**

Comment: Apt answer !  upvoted Justification for the necessity of war for the restoration of dharma, can be well understood thru utankas episode

Comment: Great Answer Pradip Ji!